# operations with javascript in html document

Tags: javascript, html, operations

I want the label with id="risultato" display the area of triangle,I tried to make this,but when I pressed button "risultato:" the risult is NaN,why?
Thanks lots

code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Pbd.png

Comment: Please do not post your code in Image format. Can you please add your code in textual format?

Comment: You should use `base.value` and `altezza.value`. They are input elements, so the `value` fields contains the actual input

Comment: `value` is missing. `NaN` means its not a number. Since you are not taking value, its not getting integer and hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting NaN because of this:

```
var altezza = document.getElementById('altezza');
var base = document.getElementById('base');
(base*altezza/2)
```

getElementById() does exactly that - gets the element. You just need to get the value from the element e.g. `var altezza = document.getElementById('altezza').value;`